# Efficiently shift elements right by one in an __mm256 vector

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization

The code below correctly shifts `v256f_stats` by one and puts the results into `v256f_x3`. This is then used to get the delta between `n[1..7] and n[0..6]`. The undefined element in the output is not an issue.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
// create a shift-by-1 copy
v256f_x1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(v256f_stats, v256f_stats, 0);
v256f_x2 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(v256f_stats, v256f_stats, 0x11);
v256f_x1 = _mm256_permute_ps(v256f_x1, 0b10010011);
v256f_x2 = _mm256_permute_ps(v256f_x2, 0b10010011);
v256f_x3 = _mm256_blend_ps(v256f_x1, v256f_x2, 0b11100000);
```

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Comment: If this is off-topic, it's because of the _missing review context_ category. You should explain what the wider program is doing (or attempting to do), and show more contextual code.

Comment: Is AVX2 available? Your code looks as if you carefully avoided AVX2 and used only AVX1 instructions.

Comment: AVX2 is available, although because of the non-lane-crossing limitation, I didn't see any instructions that would help.

Comment: @Reinderien I don't see how that would be helpful. I did explain that the code is used to determine deltas. Going further than that is superfluous. I'm only interested in the shift operation. The fact it's part of a scoring algorithm isn't helpful.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking for a code review, which makes this more of a how to question. This is definitely off-topic for this site.

Comment: Providing an explanation is a rule of the Code Review community. Omitting it in your question renders your question off-topic and deserves a downvote.

Comment: Is it me or this question was closed because several people did not know what it is about?

Comment: @IamIC could you give more surrounding/supporting information about what your code is doing?  I think that some of us are getting wrapped up in the brevity of the code that you posted for review.

Comment: The question was closed, so I'm going to have to leave it at that. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AVX2, it could be done with one `vpermps` aka `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps`:

```
auto shifted = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(v256f_stats, _mm256_set_epi32(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0));
```

Clang rewrites the original shuffle [into the same assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Zbq3uJ).

---

Here is an alternative with just AVX1:

```
auto stats00 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(v256f_stats, v256f_stats, 0);
stats00 = _mm256_blend_ps(stats00, v256f_stats, 0b01111111);
auto shifted = _mm256_permute_ps(stats00, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3));
```

Roughly the same idea as the original, but reworked so that the `_mm256_permute_ps` comes after the blend so it only needs to be done once.

This time Clang is too clever for its own good, it [replaces the blend/shuffle with two shuffles](https://godbolt.org/z/WeR493), which is worse because the blend was cheaper (p015, while the shuffles are p5).

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Is the AVX1 version as efficient as it can be? My code has dual paths. In this case, I didn't know how to use AVX2.

Comment: @IamIC I've added a better AVX1 version

Comment: Nicely done, sir!

Comment: This answer does not appear to review the code in question. Please avoid off-topic questions in the future. See [rolfl's answer to How to prevent people from answering off-topic questions?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8946/188857) for more information.

Comment: @L.F. That meta question is about those asking about their broken code. The code in this question clearly is not broken.